# Agora Web SDK ios implementation

Tags: ios, reactjs, web, video, agora.io

Using agora io's web sdk, I am simply trying to connect to a video call/stream. Per the docs below, safari and ios are supported although there are known issues. They also have a way to deal with autoplay blocking, but it raises more questions about implementation than it answers. My question is, has anyone successfully implemented Agora web sdk using react and been able to access video, 1-1 && many, using safari on ios? how did you go about it? Could you provide any code snippets and or links to examples that deal with this scenario? Ideally I would like implement something like what agora shows on their 17 person multistream example below, but when I try to access the page using ios it disconnects and goes back to the initial screen.

Agora docs - supported web browsers:
https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/browser_support#ios

Agora docs - dealing with autoplay:
https://docs.agora.io/en/Audio%20Broadcast/autoplay_policy_web?platform=Web

Agora docs - web on mobile:
https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/web_on_mobile

Agora example - multistream:
https://github.com/AgoraIO/Advanced-Video/tree/master/Web/17-Multistream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Agora SDK supports IOS web. Please use only Safari browser since other browsers don't have the necessary permissions from apple to perform webrtc calls

Tutorial: https://medium.com/agora-io/building-a-group-video-chat-app-bc05e8962c41

Demo: https://digitallysavvy.github.io/group-video-chat/

Comment: Please have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74223998/agorartcexception-agorartcerror-ws-abort-type-ping